# How to query using a box in sqlx?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

This code works without the "AND topleft..." and its `.bind()`.

```
async fn dbtest(
    Extension(pool): Extension<PgPool>,
) -> Result<String, (StatusCode, String)> {
    let row = sqlx::query_as::<_, Bin>(r#"
            SELECT id, token, start, topleft[0] AS x, topleft[1] AS y, count
            FROM bins
            WHERE callsign = $1
            AND topleft <@ BOX $2
        "#)
        .bind("SOMETAGVALUE")
        .bind("(90500000000.0,135700000000.0)(90600000000.0, 135800000000.0)")
        .fetch_one(&pool)
        .await
        .unwrap();
    Ok(format!("{:?}", row))
}
```

I've tried defining the `topleft` condition by as a `String` (here) and previously as four dollar substitutions, which resulted in a syntax error.

This code gives the error:

```
{ severity: Error, code: "42601", message: "syntax error at or near \"$2\"", ...
```

Interestingly SQLx appears to be inserting newlines and spaces, in particular, a space between `<` and `@`:

```
db.statement="\n\nSELECT\n  id,\n  token,\n  start,\n  topleft [0] AS x,\n  topleft [1] AS y,\n  count\nFROM\n  bins\nWHERE\n  callsign = $1\n  AND topleft < @ BOX $2\n"
```

How can I add a `BOX` condition to this query?

(I've already found that I needed to separate the `topleft` `POINT` into `x` and `y` parts, as SQLx did not like `POINT`s.)

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but shouldn't there be a comma between the points? i.e. `...00000.0),(9060000...`.

Comment: _"Interestingly SQLx appears to be inserting newlines and spaces, in particular, a space between `<` and `@`"_ -- This is likely the problem, looks like a bug in sqlx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
    let row = sqlx::query_as::<_, Bin>(r#"
            SELECT id, token, start, topleft[0] AS x, topleft[1] AS y, count
            FROM bins
            WHERE callsign = $1
            AND topleft <@ BOX (POINT($2,$3),POINT($4,$5))
        "#)
        .bind("SOMETAGVALUE")
        .bind(0500000000.0)
        .bind(135700000000.0)
        .bind(90600000000.0)
        .bind(135800000000.0)
        ...
```

It was the stringiness of the box definition which was confusing the argument substitution.

SQLx appears to lack mapping between Rust and Postgres geometric types.  You can use them, but they can't traverse the SQLx interface.